# React bad practice to use ReactDOM.render and inject component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I never really do this but I might have to for a certain problem I'm facing with a 3rd party library.

Basically, Is it bad to do something like

```
const fooEl = document.querySelector('.foo-class');
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
const id = 'testingId';
newDiv.id = id;
foolEl.appendChild(newDiv);

ReactDOM.render(
    <FooBarComponent />
  document.getElementById(id)
);
```

If so is there any other way I can approach this? Basically i'm trying to insert a component into a DOM element.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is perfectly valid code. Opinions about whether it's good or bad are off-topic for stack overflow

Comment: @FredStark, I think there is a difference between asking for a "best" practice (i.e an opinionated view of which method is better than any other method) and asking if an approach is "bad" (i.e if there are any known side-effects that can be avoided through another method). OP seems to be asking about the latter. The answer here, as you said yourself, is *no* - there's nothing inherently wrong with this code... but that doesn't make it opinionated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it bad to do something like...

No, the code you have there is fine, except that you forgot a `,` in your `ReactDOM.render()`. 
Other than that, there is nothing "bad" about it. You could achieve the same result with less lines if you instead did:

```
const fooEl = document.querySelector('.foo-class');
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
foolEl.appendChild(newDiv);

ReactDOM.render(
  <FooBarComponent />,
  newDiv
);
```

However, it is not clear from your question why you need to mount the React app to a child `div` of `.foo-class`, rather than just mounting it on `foo-class` directly - like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <FooBarComponent />,
  document.querySelector('.foo-class')
);
```

Comment: I'd be very happy to know why this was down-voted. Is there something I missed or that I can improve? Please let me know, because the reason is unclear to me.

Comment: I never down-voted, but have spotted an oddity in your first snippet.  `document.getElementById(newDiv)`,  well `newDiv` is already a DOM element, and doing `getElementById` on it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Keith, Well spotted. A hasty copy-paste error on my part :) Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's the correct practice, you can see that in react documentation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINWE.png)

Another altenative is centralize that in an object apart.